# Is the sentence "A lot of resources is available" correct?

Tags: grammar, subcontinental-english

I recently came across this sentence :

> A lot of resources is available:

quoted from the webpage http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm. Since this is a very reputed website, I don't think that can be a wrong grammar.

From my understanding of grammar. I think that the sentence should be

> A lot of resources are available:

Please guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, on the page you listed, *a lot of resources is available* is incorrect (though it might be correct in some other cases).

According to Swan,

> "When *a lot* is used with a plural word, the verb is plural; when *lots* is used with a singular word, the verb is singular."

The correct form here would be *"[A lot of / Many] resources are available."*

Comment: This is perhaps not as naive a question as it might appear. In a not too distant neck of the woods we have 'His means **are** more than adequate' (financial resources) but 'The best means of securing the cooperation of the builders **is** to appeal to their self-interest.' (strategy / method / agency). [AHDEL; usage note.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/means) So 'means' is [treated as being] both singular and plural.

Comment: And in fact 'resources' is also massified: _Human resources is the set of individuals who make up the workforce of an organization, business sector, or economy._ [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_resources)  subjects

[Towson](http://www.towson.edu/ows/sub-verb.htm) has: 8.  Plural form subjects – Plural form subjects with a singular meaning take a singular verb. (e.g. news, measles, mumps, physics ... [means, politics, resources ... in some of their senses]

Comment: An auction catalogue could offer "a lot of Dresden dinner-plates is available as lot 756," just to throw a spanner in (not into the china, obviously).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Surely the first 'lot' there is used as a noun though, somewhat a synonym to 'set'?

Comment: Yes, but it could easily be "A lot of resources is available as lot 756". Just saying that "a lot of [plural noun] is" is not necessarily wrong.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Hmm, true enough. But in the OP's example sentence it isn't correct, right? (Admittedly, I'm pretty loopy today)

Comment: The point is that the answer to the question *Is the sentence “A lot of resources is available” correct?* is "Maybe."

Comment: Edited... Is it better now? @AndrewLeach