# Shouldn’t we use "lots of" with plural nouns and "a lot of" with singular ones?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, countable-nouns, quantifiers

Is it correct to say "there are a lot of aspects" like [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fbusinessinsider%2Fposts%2F10152696044394657%3Fstream_ref%3D10&ei=YkjMU_qAB-up8QH9iIHQCw&usg=AFQjCNHwHqKTJVBIOuVuKW4y43HAxK8MWA&bvm=bv.71198958,d.b2U) (see the first comment) or [here](http://www.uwc.org/how_to_apply/student_profiles/uwcusa/rose.aspx)?

Shouldn't be "lots of" used instead? I was sure that the correct form is "lots of" for the plural form.

Comment: Why? Plural subjects take plural verbs.

Comment: What would make something 'correct' or 'incorrect'?

Comment: There's a [hugely related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160955/is-the-sentence-a-lot-of-resources-is-available-correct) in the "Related" sidebar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plural or singular when stating that an amount is enough](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112109/plural-or-singular-when-stating-that-an-amount-is-enough)

Comment: @tchrist, I was sure the correct form is "lots of" for the plural form.

Comment: @less.wrong Oh I see. Well, that’s a different matter. I suggest you edit your question to explain that part.

Comment: @nohat Agreed that terms like ‘correct’ and ‘incorrect’ are of course inapplicable in a linguistic context. The issue though is that ESL students get things marked right or wrong on their exams, and they want to know why.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of things means a large number (plural) of things, hence you will use a plural noun (unless the noun is uncountable, then singular).  *A lot of apples*, *a lot of chairs*, *a lot of questions*, (but *a lot of water*, *a lot of sand*).

Lots is just the plural form of lot.  And so more than one  set of a large number of things is, well, still a large number of things (and thereby plural), so you still need a plural noun (same exception for uncountables).  *Lots of apples*, *lots of chairs*, *lots of questions*, (but *lots of water*, *lots of sand*).

They will both generally agree in the plural, although when the focus on a group as a single unit, the singular agreement is possible.

Answer (score 3):

The source that the questioner links actually says

> There's a lot of aspects of being in power that seem "unfair."

The writer has apparently chosen the singular *'s (is)* to agree with *lot.* That makes a certain amount of sense, but “a lot of” followed by a countable noun in the plural has come to be most often used as if it were *many,* and we would say “There *are* many aspects . . .”—so likewise most English speakers and writers use “There *are* a lot of . . . .” Note how this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there+are+a+lot+of%2Cthere+is+a+lot+of%2C+there+are+lots+of&year_start=1860&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows “there *are* a lot of” as more frequent than  “there *is* a lot of” even though many instances of the latter must be with non-count nouns, as in “there *is* a lot of resentment on both sides.”

P.S.: In response to revision of question, I have revised my NGram link to show “there are lots of” running *third* in popularity.

Comment: You don’t ever try to match the number of *a **lot/bunch/handful** of* before a noun; those are decoys. The actual grammatical number of the verb agrees with the noun which that phase modifies. But I think the OP somehow thinks that ***lots** of* is used with plural nouns but ***a** lot of* with singular ones, which is not true of course.

Comment: For those interested, [this post](https://www.englishforums.com/English/ALotSingularOrPlural/zmlpb/post.htm) elaborates on the difference in using singular or plural verbs with constructions like "a lot of".